# Airflow DAG 'start_date' not registering

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have an Airflow environment setup that correctly points to the DAGS I'm working with. One DAG isn't loading because its import is failing

```
[2020-06-05 19:09:15,814] {dagbag.py:205} ERROR - Failed to import: /home/…/tmp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/data/environments/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 511, in dag
    dag.add_task(self)
  File "/data/environments/airflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 1124, in add_task
    raise AirflowException("Task is missing the start_date parameter")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Task is missing the start_date parameter
```

The exception keeps saying my start date is missing, but that can't be right since this is the DAG definition

```
dag_args = {
    'owner': 'owner',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 1, 1),
    'email': [email],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id=dag_name,
    default_args=dag_args,
    schedule_interval=daily_at_12_UTC
)
```

I've followed documentation and there's nothing else regarding this. Is it a formatting/syntax issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The issue has nothing to do with the DAG configuration itself. I had simply forgotten to include `dag=dag` as a parameter on one of the operators. Doing that has allowed the DAG to be correctly listed now.

Comment: Can you clarify what you did for an answer by giving the full code context?

Answer (score 0):

Since OP never followed up, I'll leave my comment here as the answer below. Note that the second to last line is the key (i.e., 'dag=dag').

```
dag_args = {
    'owner': 'owner',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 1, 1),
    'email': [email],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    dag_id=dag_name,
    default_args=dag_args,
    schedule_interval=daily_at_12_UTC,
    dag=dag
)
```